# Rails: Why isn't the 'create' action saving the newly created Quiz instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

My form gets passed a 'new' Quiz (not saved to the database). My form partial looks like this:

```
<%= form_for(@quiz) do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer1) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer2) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer3) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer4) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer5) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer6) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer7) %>
    <%= f.check_box(:answer8) %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit("Get my results!") %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

Here is my QuizzesController#create action:

```
def create
    @results = Quiz.create(post_params) #from private method
    if @results.save
        redirect_to results_path
    else
        #error handle here
    end
end
```

...which gets triggered when the user clicks 'get my results' on my quiz form. And the post_params method looks like this:

```
def post_params
    params.require(:quiz).permit(:id, :user_id, :answer1, :answer2, :answer3, :answer4, :answer5, :answer6, :answer7, :answer8) #add other attributes here
end
```

My results/index.html.erb looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Results</h1>
        <p><%= @results.inspect %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But that 'inspected' Quiz instance returns 'nil' for all the answers1, answers2 etc attributes. Any idea why that would be? Is there something I'm NOT doing to save the user's answers to the database?

Comment: Make it as @results = Quiz.new(post_params)

Comment: Could you post the private method `post_params`

Comment: post_params method added, above. @RubyOnRails : Doesn't 'new' make a new instance but NOT save it? If you're right, at what point do I save the user's answers?

Comment: a leading contender for this sort of thing is using attr_accessor for database backed attributes

Comment: Yes you can save the answer.

Comment: @RubyOnRails : OK, but I was asking WHEN would I do that. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it shows nil is because you are not setting the variable.

After creating and saving, you redirect to `results_path` and the variable `@results` does not persist during a redirect. Without seeing the full code, I'll have to guess at your naming conventions but there are two ways to do this.

1) If you want to redirect to the index then in the code for your index action, you can set the variable:

```
@results = Quiz.last
```

This is easy to work with in development because you are the only user and this will always return the last quiz you created. Not so great in production.

2) The alternative is to redirect to the show action for that quiz.

```
def create
  @results = Quiz.new(post_params)
  if @results.save
    redirect_to result_path(@results)
  else
    # error handle here
  end
end
```

Again, I have had to guess that `result_path` is the correct path. Without seeing the full routes file, I cannot be sure but you can rename accordingly if necessary.

Comment: I would make a guess that it should be `redirect_to quiz_path( @results )` ? or just `redirect_to @results`, both which are rather misleading.

Comment: Why does an instance @variable not persist through a redirect? That seems a bit of an inconsistent blockage... But thanks for the reply. At the moment I have a resource: results so there's a result_path that points to results/index. I'll have a go at switching that to quizzes/show

Comment: The structure is such that each view only has access to the variables declared in its own controller action (or those assigned via `application_controller.rb`. When you redirect, the relevant action is `index` so only variables assigned there are accessible.

Comment: I'm sorry - I've had another look at it and I don't know how to get the 'create' action pointing to the 'show' view without using a redirect_to - but then the instance variables don't persist! What hasn't clicked here for me? There's something amiss...

Comment: Sorry again! I can point to the create view! Please let me know if that's not the right thing to do though.

Comment: You need a separate action in your controller. Each route will map to a specific controller action. What happens is the form posts to the `create` action, which enters the information in the database and then redirects to the `show` action to show that information. So, you need to define the `show` action in your controller. Take a look at the [controller and routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) for more detail.